# How to store/retrieve an Apache-poi workbook object into/from Oracle blob column?

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-poi

Java 1.7, Apache-poi-3.8, JDBC

Requirements :
1) Create a workbook object with full data (which is coming from the DB).without any file creation at server.

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); // this object I want to store in DB blob column, without any file creation at server.

insertDataToCells(wb, "output", data); // this method will insert data in cells of workbook.

**//TODO code to store wb in blob column.** // How to store ?
```

2) Retrieve the data(workbook) from blob and convert this into excel and send into mail attachment

```
// TODO How to retrive
```

**Following Approach :**

```
byte[] byteArray = wb.getBytes();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
ps.setBinaryStream(1, is, 1000000); // Here i am having some confusion 
ps.execute // Successfully stored in blob column.
```

While retrieving getting error file corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set properly the number of bytes in the stream so in your case it should rather be:

```
byte[] byteArray = wb.getBytes();
ps.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray), byteArray.length);
...
```

Then to retrieve the content of your column as an `InputStream` use [`getBinaryStream(String columnLabel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream-java.lang.String-) or [`getBinaryStream(int columnIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream-int-).

Comment: true :) I was giving length 1000000, because of that it was becoming corrupt file.